# how to upgrade openGL in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I tried to set up glew and then devIL/openIL in visual studio but still have runtime and link error .
I want to know it can be from openGL version of my visual studio or what?
what should i do for upgrading my openGL?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you copy the link errors ?

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ilInit@0 referenced in function _main

Comment: ilInit is not part of OpenGL.

Comment: i know. its part of DevIL .and i want to set up Devil in my program!!

Answer (score 1):

> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp__ilInit@0 referenced in
>   function _main

You're calling but not defining `ilInit()`.  Try linking against `DeviL.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL library can't be upgraded. GLew should do the work to dynamically retrieve new functions pointers. Are you sure you are linking against opengl32.lib ?